# How can I know the process name which is opening a tcp port?

Tags: networking, centos, tcp, lsof, netstat

I have two linux servers. Let's say they are `C` and `S`.
`C` is client of `S`

On my `S` machine, I type.

> $ netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED
>   tcp        0      0 192.168.1.220:3306        **C:57010**     ESTABLISHED

Then I can know `C` is connecting now.
In the `C` machine, I'd also like to know the *process name* which is opening the port **57010** and  connecting the `S` server.
How can I do that? Of course I have root permission of `C`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to say `lsof -i:57010 -sTCP:ESTABLISHED`. This walks the kernel's open file handle table looking for processes with an established TCP connection using that port. (Network sockets are file handles on *ix type systems.) You'd use `-sTCP:LISTEN` on the server side to filter out only the listener socket instead.

Because of the way `lsof` works, it can only see processes your user owns unless you run it as root. It's also fairly inefficient, since a typical *ix system has a *lot* of file handles open at any given time. The `netstat` method given in another answer is faster and usually has lower access requirements.

The `lsof` method has one great advantage, however: not all *ix type OSes have a `netstat` flag for including the process name in the output, whereas [`lsof` has been ported to every *ix type OS you're likely to use](ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/README). OS X's `netstat` is this way, for example. It has a `-p` option, but it does something different from `netstat -p` on Linux.

For an uncommon port number like the one in your question, you can typically get away without adding `lsof`'s `-s` flag, because a given machine is unlikely to have programs both connecting to the port and listening on it. It can be helpful to add it with port numbers like HTTP's 80, where it is likely you'll have multiple programs using that port at once.

It's fortunate that the `-s` flag is optional in many situations, because that usage only works with `lsof` version 4.81 and newer. In older versions, `-s` meant something else entirely! That's a 2008 vintage change, but it can still bite unexpectedly. RHEL 5 ships with `lsof` 4.78, for example.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `netstat -anp | grep 57010` on server *C*. But this will only work if there isn't any firewall in between which is mapping port *57010* to a different one.

Comment: oh, thank you. easy. Is there a way to see the process's command line arguments?

Comment: @Benjamin If you have process id nnn then `ps waux | grep nnn` will give you quite a bit of information. For more information yet, use `cat /proc/nnn/cmdline` though the spaces have been deleted (actually I think they are replaced by \0) so it is not easy to read.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the sake of completeness:

Using `ss` from the new Linux networking utility tool-set (`iproute2`):

```
ss -tp sport = :57010 dst 192.168.1.220
```